# Google Calendar API when access_token is invalid

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get events for a particular date range in someones google calendar. I'm doing the below:

```
    credentials = AccessTokenCredentials.from_json(token_json)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        credentials.refresh(http)
    else:
        http = credentials.authorize(http)

    service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)
    events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=None,
                                   timeMin=rfc3339(start_dt),
                                   timeMax=rfc3339(end_dt))
    events = events.execute()
```

For some reason when I get to the last line `events = events.execute()`, I get the below error:

```
AccessTokenCredentialsError: The access_token is expired or invalid and can't be refreshed.
```

When I use breakpoints, it NEVER says `access_token_expired` in my if statement. How can this always fail that use case? Is there something i'm doing wrong here for refreshing tokens?

I read the below regarding this:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.2.2

[Google access token expiration time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391225/google-access-token-expiration-time)

Comment: How did you fix it ? I am using this same method and I can't refresh the token ... I would greatly appreciate any guidance. I am using AccessTokenCredentials with an already obtained token ( manually user-consent ) I have both tokens but I can't get to refresh the token token !

Comment: My problem was that I wasn't storing the data properly for the token. I save `credentials.to_json()` to my database.

Comment: Have you been able to fix it? If 'Yes' then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try testing for `credentials.invalid`?

I have this little routine I use to ensure stored credentials are always fresh for gmail unit-testing.  It may/may not be adaptable to your situation.

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client import tools

# the stored credentials file to use for these tests
TEST_CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'testjoe.storage'


def get_credentials():
    """Utility routine to returns credentials for testing use"""

    # Location of the credentials storage file
    storage = Storage(TEST_CREDENTIALS_FILE)

    # Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret_native.json', scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify')

    # Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
    return credentials
```